# Receive an error when I using F-string for creating a connection string with Python in the Pulumi

Tags: python, azure, pulumi

I want to create a storage connection string with F-String in my code (Pulumi). The scenario and sample code are:

for example, My storage name is `test`

I received the storage name with:

```
storage_name = storage_account.name
```

I received the storage key with:

```
 storage_primary_key = pulumi.Output.all(resource_group.name, storage_account.name).apply(lambda args: storage.list_storage_account_keys(
     resource_group_name=args[0], account_name=args[1])).apply(lambda accountkeys: accountkeys.keys[0].value)
```

The output of the below are ok:

```
pulumi.export('storage name is', storage_name)
pulumi.export('storage key is', storage_primary_key)
```

output:

```
storage name is: test
storage key is: sg373dhh
```

Now, I want crate connection string with the below code:

```
conn_str = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={storage_name};AccountKey={storage_primary_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

when run this code:

```
pulumi.export('storage connection string is', conn_str )
```

But, the output is different:

```
storage connection string is "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x000002152C3233D0>;AccountKey=<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x000002152C3233D0>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

I don't know why add `<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x000002152C3233D0>` instead of true value.

Comment: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outputs that contain strings cannot be used directly in operations such as [string concatenation](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#outputs-and-strings). Since `storage_primary_key` and `storage_name` are both pulumi outputs, you get strange looking result when you concatenate them directly.

You should either use `Output.all` with `.apply` or `Output.concat` and construct your string as follows. Note that `conn_str` is again a pulumi Output:

```
    # using concat
    conn_str = pulumi.Output.concat(
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=",
        storage_name,
        ";AccountKey=",
        storage_primary_key,
        ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    )

    # using Output.all with apply
    conn_str = pulumi.Output.all(storage_name, storage_primary_key).apply(
        lambda args: f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={args[0]};AccountKey={args[1]};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    )
```